# Images are being cached even if there are changes

Tags: docker

I have on Docker an automatic build for an image based on ubuntu with some custom configurations to re-use then as base image on other specific Dockerfiles for particular projects. This works okay.

I made a change to it, committed to github which then started and did the automatic build on Docker.

From one of these other projects, I'm calling at the beginning of the Dockerfile FROM myuser/myimage but its not getting the last image with the changes, but rather it keeps caching the old one.

Shouldn't this be automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `docker pull` the latest version.  Docker looks for the image from FROM locally.  It doesn't notice if that tag has been updated in the registry where it came from.  I have a script that runs docker pull before building images.